# Sending Post request from Laravel For Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.7

I wanted to authenticate a user by sending a post request from server. I hit a url in browser '/test' then the closure function for this route will send a post request to '/post-login' route for authentication.

I don't wanted to send csrf token to only 'post-login' route, that's why I excluded it in verifycsrf middleware.

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
$url = 'http://localhost/fps/public/post-login';
$fields = [];

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

curl_exec($ch);
});

Route::post('/post-login',function(){
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
});
```

Suppose that user with id=1 is existed in databse. I have tried curl and guzzle but to no avail. The above solution is not authenticating a user.

Answer (score 0):

If you use controller, then this will work, with curl it wont,  because you are using curl, its grab URL and pass it to the browse, and in return you will get the results only, it wont create any session. and for `Auth::check()` it looks for session,

Comment: I wanted to achieve this functionality, can you suggest somethinh else other than curl.

Comment: sorry, with this approach, you cant achieve this.

Comment: Can you suggest another aproach.

Comment: you can try https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication api authentication with laravel pasport. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport